# Radiation heat flux of a material surrounded by another material of different emissivity

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation

The radiation heat flux of a material is calculated according to the formula mentioned in the following website:

http://web.mit.edu/calculix_v2.7/CalculiX/ccx_2.7/doc/ccx/node234.html#radiate

But what if the environment surrounding the material wasn't just normal air, but was another material. Shouldn't we take in this case the emissivity of the other material into consideration in the formula ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't we take in this case the emissivity of the other material
>   into consideration in the formula?

Yes.

For example the *radiative heat flux* between parallel plates is given by:

$$\dot{q}_{net 1 \to 2}=\frac{\sigma(T_1^4-T_2^4)}{\frac{1}{\epsilon_1}+\frac{1}{\epsilon_2}-1}$$

You can find the [full derivation here](http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node136.html).

Another example is that of [concentric spheres or cylinders](http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node137.html#SECTION07541000000000000000).

Comment: Thanks for the upvote!